# Android System service not available to Activities before onCreate

Tags: java, android

so I have a timer in a service and i get this error everytime i run it `System services not available to Activities before onCreate()` **__________________________________________________________________________________________**

---

Service code

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MyService extends Service {
    Locator locator;
    Timer myTimer;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        locator = new Locator();
        myTimer = new Timer();
    }
    private class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask
    {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    locator.TemperatureCatch();
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        MyTimerTask myTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();
            myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTimerTask, 0, 15000);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        myTimer.cancel();
    }
}
```

Toggle Button Code (if it helps this code is above the `onCreate()` Method):

```
 @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {

        if (isChecked)
        {
 startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
            Toast.makeText(this,"Check-In will be done every 15 seconds",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
            Toast.makeText(this,"Manual Check-In enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

the method i am running:

```
 public String TemperatureCatch()
    {
       /*--> this line throws the error*/ Vibrator vibrate = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        Spinner reeferchoice = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.optionselecti);
        String reeferChoicei = reeferchoice.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if(reeferChoicei.equals("Yes"))
        {
            final ToneGenerator tg = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 500);
            tg.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ABBR_ALERT);
            vibrate.vibrate(300);
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.setTitle("Temperature");
            alert.setMessage("Input Temperature in F° (-20 to 65) ");
            final EditText input = new EditText(this);
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
            alert.setView(input);
            alert.setPositiveButton("Check-In", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    temperaturei = input.getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Updated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Updater(temperaturei);
                }
            });
            alert.show();
        }
        else if (reeferChoicei.equals("No"))
        {
            temperaturei = "DRY";
            Updater(temperaturei);
        }
        return temperaturei;
    }
```

Comment: The error message explains your problem - don't try to create objects (especially those which require system APIs, but preferably as a design practice nothing at all) until onCreate() has been called.

Comment: so whats the work around?

Comment: Create the objects in onCreate() or in an even more program-flow-appropriate later method.

Comment: but then i cant use my toggle button

Comment: Sure you can - your toggle button won't even *exist* until you set your content view, and the earliest you can do that is inside onCreate()  Order in the file is irrelevant - what matters is the order in which Android calls lifecycle methods.

Comment: My toggle button is already initialized with a display adapter in my `onCreate` `options = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.optionselecti);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        options.setAdapter(adapter);` im just calling a nother method to is if its on or off, in that method is where im satrting or stoping a service

Comment: when i remove the line that gives the the `System services not available to Activities before onCreate()` error i then get a nullpointer exception. all this only begun happening when i started using the service instead of a regular timer inside my activity @ChrisStratton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message explains your problem - don't try to create objects (especially those which require system APIs, but preferably as a design practice nothing at all) until onCreate() of your Service has been called.

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    Locator locator = new Locator();
    Timer myTimer = new Timer();
    ...
```

Should be

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    Locator locator;
    Timer myTimer;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        locator = new Locator();
        myTimer = new Timer();
    }
    ...
```

Or possibly one of the other Service lifecycle methods more appropriate to what you are actually doing.

Comment: Sorry, this kept getting entered/edited wrong - until the latest revision it would have caused an NPE, so please be sure you are using what is here now.

Comment: ok now its no longer giving me the error, now its throwing a weird null pointer exception at the line ` myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTimerTask, 0, 15000);` i tried to fix it by checking that the myTimer wasnt null and now the service wont start when the button is pressed

Comment: When I first created this the "should be" code was entered wrong, make sure it exactly matches the current form.

Comment: put in the new code now im getting the `System services not available to Activities before onCreate()` error again, i've included the method the timer is excecuting in my question.

Comment: If you are still getting that error, then you have either not made the change suggested here, or you have the same mistake occurring in additional places.

Comment: i've implemented the change you suggested; i've updated the question with the changes